# Minimum and Maximum rule for words?

Tags: php, yii

In `Yii` is there is any `rule` which should define min and max number of words in textfield

I used this

```
array('text', 'length', 'min'=>5, 'max'=>40000),
```

but this is for `charecters` i need min 4 words and max 4000 words instead of `character`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You Can make custom rule for validate word length on YII side, I am considering text area name is description.

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
       array('description', 'validateWordLength'),
    );
}
```

Now the only thing you need to do is create a new method inside the model, named after the validation rule you just declared.

```
public function validateWordLength($attribute,$params)
{
    $total_words= str_word_count($object->$attribute);
    if($total_words>4000)
    {
       $this->addError($attribute, 'Your description length is exceeded');
    }
    if($total_words<5)
    {
       $this->addError($attribute, 'Your description length is too small');
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this using

> strlen()

function it gets string length

```
$s = 'hello world'; //string you want to control
if(strlen($s) > 10 /*type max or min*/){
    echo 'big than 10 <br>';
}

$b = 'hello';
if(strlen($b) < 10 /*type max or min*/){
    echo 'less than 10';
}
```